# Changing permission for directory in Apache webserver but still showing 404

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

I have an `amazon ec2` server and just installed `apache` web server and moved my directory to `/var/www`. But it was showing a `404` error. I was certain that there is some permission issue. So I just did `chmod 777` to that directory but had no luck. Since I am new to linux, I have no idea what else could be wrong. Also `phpinfo.php` shows up properly.

Comment: uh, 404 means "not found". it has nothing to do with permissions. if it was a permissions problem, it'd be 401 - access denied.

Comment: What is the actual request being made?  What is in the web server logs for that request?  As a guess I'd suspect that the web server isn't configured to allow directory listings (which is a good thing) and there isn't a default page in that directory.

Comment: But I have my directory into /var/www.Then what can be the reason?

Comment: It is just a basic get request hit from the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Apache is looking for [directoryIndex file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex), none found, thus 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Not related to the question but for security purpouses only, is not correct to set folder's permissions to 777 in a www folder. Even if your server is running locally.